# numpy: is there an `allclose(np.array, scalar)`?

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy you can use the `allclose(X, Y)` function to check element-wise for approximate equality between two arrays. Moreover, with an expression like `X==5` you can check element-wise equality between an array and a scalar.

Is there a function that combines both functionalities?? That is, can compare an array and a scalar for approximate element-wise equality??

Comment: Doesn't that work already : `np.allclose(np.zeros(10),0)` IIUC?

Comment: It is undocumented (documentation specifies array inputs). By trying it, it seems to check whether EVERY element of the array is equal to the scalar, and return a single True/False value, instead of element-wise True/False

Comment: Most docs on NumPy funcs state inputs as arrays, doesn't mean that they don't operate on scalars, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: OK. But still, it returns a single True/False value, not elementwise comparison

Comment: For elementwise comparisons, look for `np.isclose`.

Comment: Stupid me, somehow it didn't try that first. It works for array-scalar comparison too, regardless of what the documentation says. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *array* or *array-like* in the numpy documentation mostly indicates that the input is converted to an array with `np.asarray(in_arg)` or `np.asanyarray(in_arg)`. So if you input a scalar it will be converted to an scalar array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.asarray(5)    # or np.asanyarray
array(5)
```

And the functions `np.allclose` or `np.isclose` just do element-wise comparison no matter if the second argument is a scalar array, an array with the same shape or an array that correctly broadcasts to the first array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,1,0,1.00001,0.9999999])
>>> np.allclose(arr, 1)
False
>>> np.isclose(arr, 1)
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

>>> np.isclose(arr, np.ones((10, 6)))
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

So no need to find another function that explicitly handles scalars, these functions already correctly work with scalars.

Comment: Just adding to the answer: although scalars are silently converted to numpy arrays, numpy does not seem to like that. In some cases it gives a warning, and seems to prefer `[5]` to `5` as argument. However, the behavior is not consistent across all functions (as many of the numpy behaviors, unfortunately)